# How to do Selenium Datadriven using excel(or Numbers as called in mac) in Mac machine?

Tags: java, selenium, report, extent

I am using Mac machine for selenium.Now for data driven testing using excel, how do we do it on mac machine, as mac does not have excel, it has "numbers" which is similar to excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use .csv format files to store data and read data. I currently using JSON files to do the same and it works for me like a charm.